# How to define and use JSON data type in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, postgresql-9.1, laravel-5.1

How can I define `JSON` data type that is provided in `pgsql 9.4` in Laravel 5?

I need to define data type, storing and fetching data and so far could not find way to deal it in Laravel 5.1

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum/01-19-2015-eloquent-postgres-and-the-json-datatype?page=1

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In your migrations you can do something like:

```
$table->json('field_name');
```

And in your model you add the field to the `$casts` property to instruct Eloquent to deserialize it from JSON into a PHP array:

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'field_name' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

*Note: This is also relevant answer for Laravel 5.6*

Comment: >$table->json('field_name');

Is it available in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: Awesome. Overlooked that. And in order to use PostgreSQL's JSON related queries I use Raw queries?

Comment: Dunno, but I don't advise storing data in json if you want to query those values.

Comment: Checked today, you can query JSON data in Select too. PgSQL supports it natively.

Comment: we don't have data type field in mysql. Do we need JSON type field in mysql or laravel will handle automatically?

Comment: Laravel will handle it automatically. Most likely will set it a TEXT type field.

Answer (score 11):

According to Laravel documentation, 'json' is not one of the casting available types. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

You should use 'array' instead:

```
class SomeModel extends Model
    {
        protected $casts = [
            'field_name' => 'array'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: You are correct that it should be array but sadly 'json' does actually work. It shouldn't because it encourages bad use of the casts property which exists to describe what you want to cast it _to_. Saying I want to cast a JSON field _to_ JSON is nonsense but lots of people are using it. This is symptomatic of a general misunderstanding around JSON anyway, the number of times I've seen PHP array variables called $jsonSomething. JSON is a string! Always will be, it's a form of _notation_ not an object or an array.

Comment: I use `$jsonSomething` to indicate that the string is expected to be a parseable JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

For Object to JSON casting

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'table_column_name' => 'object'
    ];
}
```

For Array to JSON casting

```
 class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'table_column_name' => 'array'
    ];
}
```